# Configuring SSH server to require RSA key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, rsa

I'm trying to configure my SSH server to require users to have an RSA key. To do this I have the settings in `sshd_config` set to

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and

```
# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and

```
UsePAM no
```

Then I do `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart` to restart the server.

This seems to work to some degree, because I included my macs `rsa_key` and it lets me log in without asking for a password. However when I try to `ssh` in through a computer that I haven't included the key of, it just prompts me for my password, and then when entered, lets me in.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Also I've heard that one should do `sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart` (sshd) instead of `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart` but I have no such file.

Comment: When you're not sure what your server is doing, increase its log level (temporarily): `LogLevel DEBUG` in `sshd_config` will cause it to log just about everything (to the point of being privacy-invasive). Logs will turn up in `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/daemon` or similar.